# Как можно оптимизировать код на си убрать лишнюю локальную переменную из функции

Tags: c

Вопрос к ГУРУ.
Ломаю голову как можно убрать локальную переменную 'Search' из функции. В общем задача функции простая,  если нашли переменную 'ForNext->FOR[i].var' равную входной переменной var то делаем перезагрузку параметров. Если не нашли ничего то делаем загрузку по следующему адресу ячейки массива структур.

Вот код:

```
void pushForNext( _FORNEXT *ForNext, uint32_t var, uint32_t begin, float step, float to)
{
    if(ForNext->size < MaxQuantityForNext){

    uint32_t i = 0;
    uint8_t Search = 0; // хочу убрать

    for(i = 0; i < ForNext->size; i++){

        if(ForNext->FOR[i].var == var)
        {
            ForNext->FOR[i].begin = begin;
            ForNext->FOR[i].step = step;
            ForNext->FOR[i].to = to;

            Search = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(Search == 0){
    ForNext->FOR[ForNext->size].var = var;
    ForNext->FOR[ForNext->size].begin = begin;
    ForNext->FOR[ForNext->size].step = step;
    ForNext->FOR[ForNext->size].to = to;

    ForNext->size = ForNext->size + 1;
    }

    }
}
```

Хочу оптимизировать и убрать локальную переменную 'Search' не изменив функционал.

Comment: а Вы не путаете оптимизацию и просто нормальный код?

Comment: @KoVadim Давайте назовём это рефакторингом )

Comment: это ближе к тому, что Вы сделали

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понял, то просто меняете `break` на `return` и выкидываете все конструкции, где фигурирует `Search`.

```
void pushForNext( _FORNEXT *ForNext, uint32_t var, uint32_t begin, float step, float to)
{
    if(ForNext->size < MaxQuantityForNext)
    {
        uint32_t i = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < ForNext->size; i++)
        {
            if(ForNext->FOR[i].var == var)
            {
                ForNext->FOR[i].begin = begin;
                ForNext->FOR[i].step = step;
                ForNext->FOR[i].to = to;

                return;
            }
        }

        ForNext->FOR[ForNext->size].var = var;
        ForNext->FOR[ForNext->size].begin = begin;
        ForNext->FOR[ForNext->size].step = step;
        ForNext->FOR[ForNext->size].to = to;

        ForNext->size = ForNext->size + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавлю от себя. Самые распространённые операторы меняющие ход программы: `break`, `continue` - если надо перестать выполнять под-программу и пойти на следующий виток цикла (хорошо работает внутри switch). `return` - если надо прервать под-программу и выйти из функции.

Comment: Насколько безопасно использование 'return' ?

Comment: @zhilenkov По факту в вашем коде после `Search = 1; break;` никакой другой код в функции уже не выполнится, если посмотреть логику, т.е. это полностью идентично `return` в данном случае.